# Error in connection with localhost and phpmyadmin - wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I had a strange error ,, 
I have wampserver installed
whenever I try to start localhost I get that error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

however, when I try to connect to 127.0.0.0 ... It connects .. !!!
I tried to edit the config file and allow the access from localhost and allow it from all but it didn't work !

and when I try to open phpMyAdmin I get that error

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I tried many online solution but they didn't work ,, any help ?!

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com - they're geared towards sysadmin stuff.

Comment: On which OS are you working?

Comment: windows 8 - Thx @Crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**
"Here my WAMP installation is in the d:\wamp folder. Change it to your wamp path."

Change the file content of d:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf to the following.

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Previously, it was like this:

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Stop and Restart your WAMP server after making these changes.

**Solution 2**
Just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

This works: http:// 127.0.0.1/
This works: http:// 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/